# Chessboardjs setup works but pieces won't "drop"

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, chess, chessboard.js

i'm copying the exact example from the chessboardjs documentation. All images appear and the board is drawn, and pieces can be picked up, but not dropped.

Here is my code, which is virtually just example #4000 from the page. https://chessboardjs.com/examples#4000

sidetest.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".\node_modules\@chrisoakman\chessboardjs\dist\chessboard-1.0.0.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myBoard" style="width: 400px"></div>
    <button id="ruyLopezBtn">Ruy Lopez</button>
    <button id="startPositionBtn">Start Position</button>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src=".\node_modules\@chrisoakman\chessboardjs\dist\chessboard-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sidetest.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My javascript "sidetest.js"

```
function onChange(oldPos, newPos) {
    console.log('Position changed:')
    console.log('Old position: ' + Chessboard.objToFen(oldPos))
    console.log('New position: ' + Chessboard.objToFen(newPos))
    console.log('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
}

var config = {
    draggable: true,
    position: 'start',
    onChange: onChange
}
var board = Chessboard('myBoard', config)

$('#ruyLopezBtn').on('click', function () {
    var ruyLopez = 'r1bqkbnr/pppp1ppp/2n5/1B2p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R'
    board.position(ruyLopez)
})

$('#startPositionBtn').on('click', board.start)
```

Does anyone know why everything seems to work except the last part, placing down pieces?

Comment: try including the full version of jQuery instead of the full version

Comment: Thank you!!! How did you know this haha. tysm

Comment: Actually I've never even used ChessBoardJS in my entire life. but the fact that it was working on the site and not for you, was some mistake in the inclusion. this happened with me all the time, when I used to include the bootstrap starter template which had the slim version, so my ajax never worked.

Comment: use this example it seems you only copied some portion of the code.
https://chessboardjs.com/examples#5000

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Needed full version of jQuery instead of slim. Answer from the comments.