# Everything working on chessboardjsx but pieces won't drop

Tags: reactjs, chess

my issue is very similar to this one: [Chessboardjs setup works but pieces won't "drop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67909106/chessboardjs-setup-works-but-pieces-wont-drop)
except I'm using react and chessboardjsx instead of chessboard.js.
My code is just basic sample usage for chessboardjsx but it's working differently than on the website. It should allow me to move the pieces anywhere but they just won't drop. Here's my code:

```
import "./App.css";
import Chessboard from "chessboardjsx";

const App: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <div className="flex-center">
      <h1>Random Chess</h1>
      <Chessboard
        position="start"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I don't know if i'm somehow importing chessboardjsx wrong or if it was updated and i'm not aware of it, but I honestly don't know what to do. If anyone knows why I can't drop the pieces or has any suggestions, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I have the exact same issue currently

Comment: @Jonathan I believe the problem is that chessboardjsx hasn’t updated to work with new versions of react. I decided to switch to using the @react-chess/chessground package which has worked very well. That’s my suggestion.

Comment: I actually moved to react-chessboard